# jQuery Validation Plugin cannot Validate on Keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I use jQuery Validation Plugin and my form can be validated as below (let's say I have 2 fields A and B):

**It Works:** 
I **clicked A** and type something and then delete. Then I **clicked B**. In that case validation message is shown.

**It DOES NOT Work:**
I **clicked A and do not type nothing. Then I clicked B. In that case the related validation message related to field A is not shown. But I want it to shown as above.

I tried to use onsubmit, onkeyup and onclick parameters in validate method, but it did not make any sense. How can I provide this?

**Razor:**

```
jQuery(function () {
    $.validator.setDefaults(
    $("#myform").validate({
        //onsubmit: false, ???
        //onkeyup: true, ???
        //onclick:true, ???
        onkeyup: function(element){this.element(element);},
        rules: {
            'Applicant.Name': "required",
            'Applicant.Surname': "required"
        },
        messages: {
            'Applicant.Name': "Please enter your Name",
            'Applicant.Surname': "Please enter your Surname"
        }
    })
); 

});
```

Comment: please add your selector code, then we can see what is missing...

Comment: @SerdarBuyuktemiz: I added at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code:

```
jQuery(function () {
    $.validator.setDefaults(
        $("#myform").validate({ .... })
    ); 
});
```

**IMPORTANT:  You cannot put the `.validate()` method inside of `.setDefaults()`.**  It makes no sense.

- The `.validate()` method is for initializing the plugin (with options) on a form.
- The `.validator.setDefaults()` method is for setting the options that will apply to all forms on the page, however, this method will not *initialize* anything.

If you want to set your options for `#myform`, *only* use [`.validate()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate)...

```
jQuery(function () {
    $("#myform").validate({
        // options only for #myform
    });
});
```

If you want to set your options for use on *all* forms on the page, use [`.validator.setDefaults()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/).  Then use `.validate()` on every form...

```
jQuery(function () {

    $.validator.setDefaults({
        // options for all forms on page
    });

    $("#myform").validate({
        // options only for #myform
    });

    $("#myform2").validate({
        // options only for #myform2
    });

});
```

---

**Default plugin operation:**

By default, the plugin does not do any "key-up" validation until *after* the field is initially validated by another event.

So here is a properly modified version of the default `onkeyup` callback function so it will provide *immediate* `onkeyup` validation.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/QfKk7/**

```
onkeyup: function (element, event) {
    if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "") {
        return;
    } else {
        this.element(element);
    }
}
```

---

Your code:

```
//onsubmit: false, ???
//onkeyup: true, ???
//onclick:true, ???
```

These options **must never** be set to `true`.

**Documentation:**

> **onfocusout**
>  Type: Boolean or Function()
>   **Validate elements (except checkboxes/radio buttons) on blur**. If nothing is entered, all rules are skipped, except when the field was
>   already marked as invalid. Set to a Function to decide for yourself
>   when to run validation.  **A boolean true is not a valid value**.

---

> **onkeyup**
>  Type: Boolean or Function()
>   **Validate elements on keyup**. As long as the field is not marked as invalid, nothing happens. Otherwise, all rules are checked on each key
>   up event. Set to false to disable. Set to a Function to decide for
>   yourself when to run validation.  **A boolean true is not a valid
>   value**.

---

> **onclick**
>  Type: Boolean or Function()
>   **Validate checkboxes and radio buttons on click**. As long as the field is not marked as invalid, nothing happens. Otherwise, all rules are checked on each key
>   up event. Set to false to disable. Set to a Function to decide for
>   yourself when to run validation.  **A boolean true is not a valid
>   value**.

---

> **onsubmit**
>  Type: Boolean or Function()
>   **Validate the form on submit**. As long as the field is not marked as invalid, nothing happens. Otherwise, all rules are checked on each key
>   up event. Set to false to disable. Set to a Function to decide for
>   yourself when to run validation.  **A boolean true is not a valid
>   value**.

Comment: Dear Sparky, Thanks a lot for perfect explanations (I voted up). But my need is  a little bit different. Could you please revise the code so that providing this scenario? When the User directly click to Field A there will not be any validation. After  clicking to another field (or Field A lost focus) Field A will be validated (validation should not be done after each key up, it should be done after the related input lost focus). In addition to this, if the User directly click to Submit button without clicking to any field, all the related fields should be validated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @H.Johnson, if validation should not be done on each key up, what happens when you simply set the `onkeyup` option to `false`?

Comment: It seems to be worked. But the strange thing is that, Althought all the validation rules, entity rules, class, etc. are the same for Name and Surname fields, it works one of them for the first validation (clicking X field and typing something then focusing another field and then clearing text on the X field). I think it is not a known symptom, so I will examine the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @H.Johnson, please read the part of my answer that explains the "default" behavior.

Comment: I have tried the modified version of the default onkeyup provided by you but it did not work. So I further modified it and by chance it is working good.  Here is my code : **onkeyup: function (element, event) {
    if (element.value === "") {
        return;
    } else {
        this.element(element);
    }
}**

Sparky, can you please explain your modified code.

Comment: @ErFaiyazAlam, my version works; it ignores validation when the field is empty while using the "tab" key, otherwise, it validates on every key-up immediately.  In other words, it's _exactly_ the same as what's built into the plugin except that it's "eager" rather than "lazy".  Your version is the same as mine, except the "tab" key will also trigger validation.  It's a matter of preference.

Comment: @Sparky,thank you for your response.Basically I want to know that what does this line of code do exactly : **event.which === 9**

Comment: @ErFaiyazAlam, since that's the piece you deleted, its purpose is revealed in my previous comment by logical inference.  **It's the tab key event**.

Comment: @Sparky, yes I got it and thanx for you help.